# NSTrackingArea call custom code

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstrackingarea

How can I call my own method when the area defined by NSTrackingArea captures mouse events? Can I specify my own method (e.g. "myMethod") in the NSTrackingArea init as below?

```
trackingAreaTop = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,100,100) options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:myMethod userInfo:nil];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I specify my own method (e.g. "myMethod") in the NSTrackingArea init as below?
>
> ```
> trackingAreaTop = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,100,100) options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:myMethod userInfo:nil];
> ```

No. The `owner` is supposed to be an object to receive the requested mouse-tracking, mouse-moved, or cursor-update messages, not a method. It won't even compile if you pass in your custom method.

> How can I call my own method when the area defined by NSTrackingArea captures mouse events?

`NSTrackingArea` only defines the area that is sensitive to the movements of the mouse. In order to respond to them, you need to:

1. Add your tracking area to the view you want to track using the `addTrackingArea:` method.
2. Optionally implement the `mouseEntered:`, `mouseMoved:` or `mouseExited:` methods in your `owner` class as per your need.

---

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:frame options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited owner:self userInfo:nil];
        [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }

    return self;
}    

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSPoint mousePoint = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    // do what you desire
}
```

For details, please refer to [Using Tracking-Area Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html).

---

As a aside, if you want to respond to mouse clicking events rather then mouse movement events, there is no need to use `NSTrackingArea`. Just go ahead and implement the `mouseDown:` or `mouseUp:` method instead.

Comment: Thanks Renfei. I suppose tracking areas can be created for different areas of the view and they will all map to the single mouse... events?